# Fundamental solution for the p-harmonic and p-biharmonic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, boundary-value-problem

I am working on $p$-Laplace equation. that is
$$\tag{1}
-\text{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)=\delta_0 \;\; in\; \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2),
$$
and the $p$-bilaplace equation, that is 
$$\tag{2}
\Delta(|\Delta u|^{p-2}\Delta u)=\delta_0 \;\; in\; \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2),
$$

In the case if $p=2$: The equation (1) can be written as
$$
-\Delta u=\delta_0 \;\; in\; \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2),
$$
then its fundamental solution is
$$\Gamma^1_2(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\ln(|x|),$$
More generally, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the fundamental solution of equation (1) is

$$
\Gamma^1_p(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{2\pi}\ln(|x|),&\; if\; p=n,\\
|x|,&\; if\; p=\infty,\\
|x|^{(p-n)/(p-1)},&\; otherwise. 
\end{cases}
$$
(ref, [book](http://umu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:445532/FULLTEXT01.pdf) page 16).

If $p=2$, the second equation can be written as 
$$
\Delta^2 u=\delta_0 \;\; in\; \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2),
$$
then its fundamental solution is
$$\Gamma^2_2(x)=-\frac{1}{8\pi}\left\lvert x\right\rvert^2\log\left\lvert x\right\rvert$$

I want to know the fundamental solution of tow equation (2) if $p\in ]1,2]$.
I tried to prove it.
I used the Green formula as following: $\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$
$$\varphi(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\Delta(|\Delta u|^{p-2}\Delta u)\varphi dx=\lim_{x\to\varepsilon}\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}|\Delta u|^{p-2}\Delta u\Delta\varphi dx-\lim_{x\to\varepsilon}\left(\int_{|x|=\varepsilon}|\Delta u|^{p-2}\Delta u\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial n} d\sigma(x)-\int_{|x|=\varepsilon}|\Delta u|^{p-2}\frac{\partial(\Delta u)}{\partial n}\varphi d\sigma(x)\right)=...$$

please there is a hint to evalute the fundamental solution $\Gamma_p^2$ for the second equation (2).

Comment: For $p<n$, the fundamental solution is $|x|^{(p-n)/(p-1)}$ where $n$ is the dimension of the space. Begin by calculating $|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u$. (By the way, you have $\Delta$ in place of $\nabla$ in many places.)

Comment: @Meta, thank you for your help, we mean that, if we replace $\nabla$ by $\Delta$ i find the same solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you also had bi-Laplace equation there. It's not advisable to mix things like that; separate questions about p-Laplace and p-biLaplace would be better. Of course their fundamental solutions are different. By the way, for $p\ne 2$ the concept of a fundamental solution is fuzzy since the equations are nonlinear.

Comment: @Meta thank you for your remark, I edit my question